# New to Angular, getting an error that my variables aren't defined even though they show up?

Tags: angular

I'm getting an error in my VScode even though my page seems to be working correctly. I'm guessing that I'm doing something wrong even though things are working.

I'm trying to push objects onto a new array outside of my ngOnInit function, and then use that array in my component with a *ngFor loop. However in my component I get the error "Identifier 'time' is not defined. '' does not contain such a member". On my vars.

I'm assuming it has something to do with the life cycle of events, maybe at the time the information isn't there?

Anyways, here is the code I'm working with:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { WeatherService } from '../weather.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { _ } from 'underscore';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-forecast',
  templateUrl: './forecast.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./forecast.component.css']
})
export class ForecastComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private weatherSub: Subscription;

  constructor(public weatherService: WeatherService) { }

  daysOfWeek = [];


  ngOnInit() {
    this.weatherSub = this.weatherService.getWeatherListener()
    .subscribe((weather: any) => {
      const daysOfWeekData = weather.weekData.data;
      const slicedDaysOfWeek = daysOfWeekData.slice(1, 6);
      _.each(slicedDaysOfWeek, (day) => {
        const days = moment.unix(day.time).format('dddd');
        day.time = days;
        this.daysOfWeek.push(day);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Here is the component code:

```
<div class="forecast-container">
  <div
  *ngFor="let day of daysOfWeek"
  class="day-container"
  >
    <p>{{day.time}}</p>
    <i class="wi wi-showers"></i>
    <p>{{day.apparentTemperatureHigh}}</p>
    <p>{{day.apparentTemperatureLow}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the code is working as I'm getting weather data. However that error scares me.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you considered creating interfaces/classes to represent the data you are expecting and manipulating instead of using `any`?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky no I haven't considered that, would this solve the error?

Comment: Did You try put `daysOfWeek = [];` in constructor ?

Comment: @Sebastianor No I did not, is that the proper way of doing it?

Comment: I would really recommend creating interfaces/classes to use in place of `any`. This will not only provide typing benefits and autocomplete of TypeScript. You don't need to move it to the constructor. If you declare in the constructor, you will not be able to use it elsewhere. Also can you share the exact error, update your question with that?

Comment: In your error, do you have the position of the error? Is it in the `.html` or in the `.ts`

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky the error is up there. that's the error I'm getting in VSCode. I'm not getting an error anywhere but VSCode.

Comment: @Wandrille I should have specified, the error I'm getting is in VSCode, so maybe it's not a huge issue?

Comment: As @Wandrille stated, it's about understanding whether the error is related to the component or if it's in the template specifically.

Comment: I agree with Alex, create interfaces. This may not be your problem but is not good practice to use `any`

Comment: try {{day?.time}}

Comment: Do you have an error in your browser console?

Comment: @ukn no, no error in the browser, only in VSCode

Comment: @Wandrille the error is in the HTML file.

Comment: Try: `daysOfWeek:any[] = [];`

Comment: @Wandrille still getting the VSCode error. Frustrating haha.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Maybe it's just an IDE shitty thing?

Comment: Perhaps this can be used for a running example and helping to resolve this issue.  At least a starting point. It could be TypeScript settings in your environment perhaps? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xhp1qh

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Fucking hell, that's what it was it's an IDE issue. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript needs to know the type of the array

```
public daysOfWeek: any[] = [];
```

or

```
interface Day {
  time: string;
  apparentTempertureHight: number;
  apparentTempertureLow: number;
}
```

then

```
public daysOfWeek: Day[] = [];
```

Comment: I'm still getting a VSCode error with the first one.

Comment: Depending on you tsconfig s and VSCode extensions the `any` might not be specific enough. I havn't seen that error about '<anonymous>' You'd need to post a more complete project for duplication.